# Update List of Picker ItemsSource

Tags: data-binding, maui

I have a Picker which is bound to a ItemsSource which is a List of KeyValuePair<string, string> also with a SelectedItem which is bound to a SelectedItem Property in my ViewModel.

```
<Picker ItemDisplayBinding=“{Binding Value}“
        ItemsSource=“{Binding PickerItemList}“
        SelectedItem=“{Binding SelectedItem}“ />
```

**ViewModel Code (not cleaned up)**

```
public partial class SettingsViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private static ILocalizationResourceManager LocalizationResourceManager;

    private Dictionary<string, string> LanguageDictionary { get; set; }

    public SettingsViewModel(ILocalizationResourceManager localizationResourceManager)
    {
        LocalizationResourceManager = localizationResourceManager;

        LanguageDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {“de“, $“{LocalizationResourceManager[“German“]}“},
            {“en“, $“{LocalizationResourceManager[“English“]}“},
        }

        if (Preferences.ContainsKey(Constants.ApplicationLanguage))
        {
            var langSetting = Preferences.Default.Get(Constants.ApplicationLanguage, “en“);
            SelectedLanguage new KeyValuePair<string, string>(langSetting, LanguageDictionary[langSetting]);
        }
    }

    public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> PickerItemList
    {
        get => LanguageDictionary.ToList();
    }


    private KeyValuePair<string, string> _selectedLanguage;
    public KeyValuePair<string, string> SelectedLanguage
    {
        get => _selectedLanguage;
        set
        {
            _selectedLanguage = value;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.Key))
            {
                 LocalizationResourceManager.CurrentCultute = new CultureInfo(value.Key);

                 // Update the List
                 LanguageDictionary.Clear();
                 LanguageDictionary.Add(“de“, $“{LocalizationResourceManager[“German“]}“);
                 LanguageDictionary.Add(“en“, $“{LocalizationResourceManager[“English“]}“);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I want to replace my PickerItemList and change values based on the SelectedItem.

So, in the SelectedItem Property, I do the change of my List which is returned then by the PickerItemList-Property.

It seems like the List is not replaced in my view. When I add an OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PickerItemList)) also my SelectedItem is called again and I run into an endless loop.

How can I replace my list and show it in my ContentPage with the updated list?

Comment: Could you please post the code of your ViewModel?

Comment: What do you think is "SelectedItem"?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT - I updated my ViewModel code. But it is not cleaned up ;) I tried to clear the list and hoped it would Update the PickerItemList, too. I can’t do an OnPropertyChanged as it get‘s into the endless loop with SelectedItem Calls and also can’t set ItemsSource to null and re-assign the list

Comment: @H.A.H. - Selected Item in my case is the Language Identifier „de“ or „en“. What I want in the end is also a changed translation which is displayed for the selected Language Identifier

Comment: What's the `ILocalizationResourceManager ` ? And if it is convenient for you, could you please post a basic demo so that we can test on our side?

Answer (score 0):

Initial dictionary:

```
LanguageDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {“de“, $“{LocalizationResourceManager[“German“]}“}, <<< Lets call this object A
            {“en“, $“{LocalizationResourceManager[“English“]}“},
        }
```

Changed dictionary:

```
LanguageDictionary.Clear();
LanguageDictionary.Add(“de“, $“{LocalizationResourceManager[“German“]}“); <<< object B
LanguageDictionary.Add(“en“, $“{LocalizationResourceManager[“English“]}“);
```

Object A and B are two completely different objects, no matter that they have the same key and value.

You can modify properties instead of replacing objects.

You can use separate property (not SelectedItem) and replace objects, only when the property actually changes.

You can save your choice in settings, and use event for selected choice change, and compare it to the settings (what I usually do).

To be honest, there are many many ways to solve your problem, so I will stop here. Including not translating the languages. Showing "deutsch" and "english", is not that bad design choice.

(If I see languages translated to Greek or Chinese, I will have to spend one afternoon to get it back to English)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by „modify properties“? When accessing changing the property with an indexer like LanguageDictionary[„de“] = „…“ with the new value, it is also not updated in the UI. Well, leaving it untranslated was also something, I was thinking about, but thought would also be a bit unusual?

Comment: @OXO This is because you need something to fire notification. Binding is one thing. Getting the changes is completely different story. If you want, you can make it translate as practice, and then decide to leave it or not. But you need to understand how to use bindings anyway.